# Removing \r\n from a Python list after importing with readlines

Tags: python, readlines

I have saved a list of ticker symbols into a text file as follows:

```
MMM
ABT
ABBV
ANF
....
```

Then I use readlines to put the symbols into a Python list:

```
stocks = open(textfile).readlines()
```

However, when I look at the list in it contains Windows end-of-line delimiter which I do not want:

```
list: ['MMM\r\n', 'ABT\r\n', 'ABBV\r\n', 'ANF\r\n', 'ACE\r\n', 'ACN\r\n', 'ACT\r\n', 'ADBE\r\n', 'ADT\r\n', 'AMD\r\n', 'AES\r\n', .....
```

Can someone suggest the easiest way to remove these unwanted characters?

Answer (score 36):

That's basically how `readlines` works.  You could post-process it:

```
stocks = [x.rstrip() for x in stocks]
```

But I prefer not using `readlines` at all if I don't want EOL character(s), instead doing:

```
stocks = open(textfile).read().splitlines()
```

Or even better:

```
with open(textfile) as f:
    stocks = f.read().splitlines()
```

(it almost certainly won't make a difference here, but using context managers to explicitly close file objects is a good habit to get into)

Comment: but read() reads until EOF. readline() reads until \r\n

Answer (score 14):

`readlines()` should never be used unless you know that the file is really small. For your application, it is better to use `rstrip()`

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        l = l.rstrip()
        # other operations.
```

Answer (score 13):

You could replace `\r\n` with the empty string in a `replace` command.

```
stocks = [x.replace("\r\n","") for x in stocks]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
stocks = open(textfile).read().splitlines()
```