# Python writing unrecognizable characters at end of line

Tags: python-3.x, csv, character

I am using a windows7 machine and I cannot figure out why Python 3 is writing this character at the end of each line ਍ഀ

Here is my code:

```
import csv

input_file = open('7.15.16.txt', 'r')
output_file = open('no_commas1.csv', 'w')
for line in input_file:
    line = line.replace(",", " ")
    output_file.write(line)
output_file.close()
input_file.close()
```

Comment: Only thing I can think of: check the encoding, you can trying opening the file with a specific encoding too: f = open(fname, encoding="utf-8").

Comment: I believe those are [newline symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) '\r\n'. Which problems it cause? Do you have them in original file?

Comment: They are not in the original file. I also cannot open the file with encoding="utf-8" - I receive an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you have a *.txt* file. So to define a new line in .txt file `\r\n` symbols are used. You will not see them if you open it in text editor. You have to turn on *invisible characters mode*. You can use [notepad++](http://mattrefghi.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/ShowAllCharacters.png) to see them.

Then you save information in *.csv* file. But *.csv* does not have a special meaning for `\r\n` symbols. As a result, they are displayed as is.

You have to remove `\r\n` symbols in your code directly. See [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24946640/removing-r-n-from-a-python-list-after-importing-with-readlines)

Answer (score -1):

```
input_file = open('7.15.16.txt', 'r', encoding='utf16')
```